# how to find value of iterative updates convergence

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, numerical-linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems

For a project, i was trying to check convergence of the iterative updates $$\begin{bmatrix}
    s_{1}\\
    s_{2} \\
    s_{3}
\end{bmatrix}:=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{s_{1} + s_{2} + 2s_{3}} + \frac{2}{2s_{1} + s_{2} + s_{3}}       & \frac{1}{s_{1} + s_{2} + 2s_{3}} & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{s_{1} + s_{2} + 2s_{3}} & \frac{1}{s_{1} + s_{2} + 2s_{3}} + \frac{1}{2s_{1} + s_{2} + s_{3}}  & \frac{1}{2s_{1} + s_{2} + s_{3}} \\
    0 & \frac{1}{2s_{1} + s_{2} + s_{3}} & \frac{2}{s_{1} + s_{2} + 2s_{3}} + \frac{1}{2s_{1} + s_{2} + s_{3}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    s_{1}\\
    s_{2} \\
    s_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$

For any random initialization of $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}$, all three seem to converge to 1. Is there any way I can find this convergence value (=$1$) or know when (for what properties of the $n$ x $n$ matrix) would $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}$ all converge to the same number?

In general, is it possible to figure out all the fixed points that a system $Ax = b$ like above will converge to?

Comment: When you say "random initialization" what precisely do you mean?  I assume you're initializing the 3 variables independently from the same distribution, but what is the distribution?

Comment: it doesn't matter. after initializing the 3 variables to any 3 real numbers, all 3 variables converge to 1

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if the initial values were restricted to being between $0$ and $1,$ say.  I phrased my question badly.

Comment: Yeah no you can check it's true for any 3 reals

Comment: It's easy to prove that if they all converge to a common limit, that limit must be $1$.  Just call the common limit $S$ and substitute $S$ for $s_1,s_2,s_3$ everywhere in your equation and solve.  That's a long way from where you want to get, though.

Comment: Have you tried any nonpositive numbers?  It's easy to find initial conditions that make a denominator $0,$ so there have to be some restrictions.

Comment: yes, i tried nonnpositive numbers as well, all 3 variables still converge to 1 (of course except when the denominators are 0).
i.e. if it ever converges, all 3 converge to the same number (1)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $(1,-2,1)$ is a fixed point.

Comment: you are right, now how would we find all such fixed points (and prove that they all converge to the same number apart from some of these fixed points)

Comment: Actually, I would expect that initial values sufficiently close to $(1,-2,1)$ would converge to $(1,-2,1).$  Have you tested that yet?

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that $(ks_1,ks_2,ks_3), k\ne 0$ goes to the same point as $(s_1,s_2,s_3),$ but I haven't been able to turn it to account.  It means in a sense, that this is really a problem in the projective plane, for what that's worth.  This is a discrete dynamical system, and I don't know anything about that, except that simple-looking problems can give rise to fractals.  I think you should add the "dynamical systems" tag to your question, in hopes of attracting someone who knows about this stuff.

Comment: (2, -4, 2) seems to converge to (1, 1, 1). Also, values very close to (1, -2, 1) seem to converge to (1, 1, 1).

Comment: Can you see where my mistake is?  Why doesn't the $k$ cancel?

Comment: I think it must be rounding in the computer program.  I get $(2,-4,2)\to(1,-2,1)$ when I do it by hand.  But it may be that (1,-2,1) is the only exception.